# Dynamic CRM new fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm

Some new fields were create in Dynamics CRM.

Now need to push some data to those new fields from asp.net website.

Need to add those new fields to:

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute()]

namespace Xrm
```

how should this be done?  I read that these is a tool that generates this class file (CrmSvcUtil.exe).

But I do not understand how this would work.

Is this something that need to be done through Dynamics CRM admin?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should be done by user which has System Administrator or System Customizer, because this user has to have access to all entities metadata.
Basically you should start with downloading CRM SDK, for your version of CRM. For example the latest SDK can be found here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032

Install the SDK and go to the bin folder inside the folder where you installed it. There you can find crmsvcutil.exe. This tool is something like svcutil.exe - it simply generates proxy classes using CRM metadata service. So instead of referring to Account entity like that:

```
var account = new Entity("account")
```

you can simply do:

```
var account = new Account();
```

and you will have all the properties that account in your system has.

In order to generate this classes just run crmsvcutil.exe using windows command line with proper credentials (it's very well documented if you run it without any parameters). example usage would be:

```
crmsvcutil /url:https://orgname.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /u:user@orgname.onmicrosoft.com /p:password /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext /out:Proxies.cs /n:Xrm
```

this would generate file Proxies.cs, containing namespace Xrm (the one you have posted in your question) with all the entities and fields. Of course the parameters may vary based on what type of organization you are connecting to. If you have problems with specifying proper values then simply put /il as last command line parameter - it will open an interactive login form, that would make it simpler for you to pass proper connection data.

Comment: For some reason when creating XRM class it does NOT contain the newly added fields.  anyway to debug this issue?

Comment: Check the version of your CRM. You should use the same version of crmsvcutil. Also you can try with older SDK (2015), because I already run into some problems myself with the latest crmsvcutil. Make sure that you are not making any "typo" error like connecting to different address, different organization, looking at different entity. Make sure you published all customizations in CRM. Also not sure if you got it but XRM is not a class, it's a namepsace and you will have classes inside e.g. Account and this will contain new fields (of course if new fields are for Account, it's only an example)